# How to break out of parent function?

Tags: python

If I want to break out of a function, I can call `return`.

What if am in a child function and I want to break out of the parent function that called the child function?  Is there a way to do this?

A minimal example:

```
def parent():
    print 'Parent does some work.'
    print 'Parent delegates to child.'
    child()
    print 'This should not execute if the child fails(Exception).' 

def child():
    try:
        print 'The child does some work but fails.'
        raise Exception
    except Exception:
        print 'Can I call something here so the parent ceases work?'
        return
    print "This won't execute if there's an exception."
```

Comment: Raise an exception and let the parent function catch it.  You can't do it without parental supervision ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what exception handling is for:

```
def child():
    try:
        print 'The child does some work but fails.'
        raise Exception
    except Exception:
        print 'Can I call something here so the parent ceases work?'
        raise Exception  # This is called 'rethrowing' the exception
    print "This won't execute if there's an exception."
```

Then the parent function won't catch the exception and it will keep going up the stack until it finds someone who does.

If you want to rethrow the same exception you can just use `raise`:

```
def child():
    try:
        print 'The child does some work but fails.'
        raise Exception
    except Exception:
        print 'Can I call something here so the parent ceases work?'
        raise  # You don't have to specify the exception again
    print "This won't execute if there's an exception."
```

Or, you can convert the `Exception` to something more specific by saying something like `raise ASpecificException`.

Comment: or just a bare `raise` if you want the original exception re-raised after some handling

Comment: At least provide a context of the previous exception. Otherwise, if something bad will happen, resulted stacktrace may be confusing.

Comment: @tommus: In Python 3, that context is automatic unless you override exception context chaining (by adding `from None` to the end of the new `raise` statement). In Py2, yes, you have to go to some trouble.

Comment: Author of the question have used Python 2 notation so I feel the need to clarify that thing. Thanks for expanding my idea.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this (works on python 3.7):

```
def parent():
    parent.returnflag = False
    print('Parent does some work.')
    print('Parent delegates to child.')
    child()
    if parent.returnflag == True:
        return
    print('This should not execute if the child fails(Exception).')

def child():
    try:
        print ('The child does some work but fails.')
        raise Exception
    except Exception:
        parent.returnflag = True
        print ('Can I call something here so the parent ceases work?')
        return
    print ("This won't execute if there's an exception.")
```