# Return from parent function in a child function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return

I know in a function you can exit the function using `return`,

```py
def function():
    return
```

but can you exit a parent function from a child function?

Example:

```py
def function()
    print("This is the parent function")

    def exit_both():
        print("This is the child function")
        # Somehow exit this function (exit_both) and exit the parent function (function)

    exit_both()
    print("This shouldn't print")

function()
print("This should still be able to print")
```

---

I tried raising an `Exception`, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35928703/12139738) suggests, but that just exits the whole program.

Comment: Note that the fact that you chose to define `exit_both` inside `function` is completely irrelevant, and just makes the situation a bit less clear than using two 'normally defined' functions.

Comment: Does this question have some connections with `tkinter`?

Comment: A function shouldn't have any knowledge of who called it in the first place; it's not the function's job to specify where a call should return *to*. Exceptions are for signalling a problem has occurred, not for directly flow control (Python's use of `StopIteration` et al aside.)

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA yes it does.

Comment: do you have to just `return`?  or return values?  I suppose return values could be accommodated by setting an exception.value for example, but that is something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can raise an exception from `exit_both`, then catch that where you call `function` in order to prevent the program being exited. I use a custom exception here as I don't know of a suitable built-in exception and catching `Exception` itself is to be avoided.

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass

def function():
    print("This is the parent function")

    def exit_both():
        print("This is the child function")
        raise MyException()

    exit_both()
    print("This shouldn't print")

try:
    function()
except MyException:
    # Exited from child function
    pass
print("This should still be able to print")
```

Output:

```
This is the parent function
This is the child function
This should still be able to print
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be this:

```
returnflag = False
def function():
    global returnflag
    print("This is the parent function")

    def exit_both():
        global returnflag
        print("This is the child function")
        returnflag = True
        return

    exit_both()
    if returnflag == True:
        return
    print("This shouldn't print")

function()
print("This should still be able to print")
```

Or if you don't like to play with global variables you can try this:

```
def function():
    returnflag = False
    # or you can use function.returnflag = False -> the result is the same
    print("This is the parent function")

    def exit_both():
        print("This is the child function")
        function.returnflag = True
        return

    exit_both()
    if function.returnflag == True:
        return
    print("This shouldn't print")

function()
print("This should still be able to print")
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using wrappers/decorators

```
class ParentShouldReturnException(Exception):
    pass


def return_from_child_wrapper(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('inside return_from_child_wrapper')
        try:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        except ParentShouldReturnException:
            print('ParentShouldReturnException was raised, returning')
            return 'forced return'
        return result
    return wrapper


def force_parent_return_if_none_wrapper(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('inside force_parent_return_if_none_wrapper')
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if result is None:
            print('raising ParentShouldReturnException')
            raise ParentShouldReturnException
        return result
    return wrapper


@force_parent_return_if_none_wrapper
def func_a(a):
    return a

@return_from_child_wrapper
def func_b(input_arg1):
   return func_a(input_arg1)


print('example 1 - normal')
result = func_b('nothing interesting')
print(f'{result=}')
print()
print('example 2 - return from child')
result = func_b(None)
print(f'{result=}')
```

this outputs

```
example 1 - normal
inside return_from_child_wrapper
inside force_parent_return_if_none_wrapper
result='nothing interesting'

example 2 - return from child
inside return_from_child_wrapper
inside force_parent_return_if_none_wrapper
raising ParentShouldReturnException
ParentShouldReturnException was raised, returning
result='forced return'
```